# Why there is a difference in payload size of MQTT and CoAP?

Tags: iot

I have one concern as I have just started working with MQTT and CoAP in my school. 
I did data packet transmission using both protocols separately, For MQTT I used mosquitto and libcoap is used for CoAP, the transmitted packet contains the information “Temperature=22*C”. I know the difference in Header sizes in the packet for both protocols. But My question is why the payload size is different even though it is containing the same information. 
I know the TCP header is larger than UDP header. But for MQTT, the payload is 22 bytes and for CoAP it is 4 bytes. Why the payload is compressed for CoAP with the same info?
Please help me with an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you consider to be the "payload". Is it the string (17 characters, maybe + terminating \000)? If so, I don't understand the 22 bytes, the 4 bytes maybe the c-pointer instead of the string. If you send that, what to you receive on the other side?

Answer (score 0):

1. As you noted TCP packet and UDP datagram sizes will differ at least due to TCP and UDP headers sizes difference.
2. MQTT message (TCP packed body) and CoAP packed (UDP datagram body) will differ at least due to MQTT & CoAP messages headers difference.
3. MQTT payload and CoAP payload (omitting MQTT and CoAP headers) might differ due to different serialization protocol. The string can be transmitted being serialized in different formats: JSON, TLV, CBOR, plaintext. You need to check what is used for each message in your case.